# How reuse groovy scripts in soapui project?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Suppose I write a groovy function. Is it possible to store it to some teststep or another place in soapui project and include it with import in other groovy test steps?

Answer (score 2):

SoapUI offers three options:

1. You can use the [script library](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html#2-groovy-script-library), where you store all your scripts in a separate directory and just call the classes.
2. You can use the [run testcase step](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/modularizing-your-tests.html), where you store your script as a test which you can call from any other test.
3. You can compile your script into a jar, place it in $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext, and then call the classes inside your jar.

Note that the first two options are -Pro only features!